# Shiny Wordcloud Generator by file input

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a Wordcloud generator that reads PDF and TXT files, the code is nowhere complete regarding the second user input (PDF).

As of now, I can upload a file but it seems to no be doing anything. Is there something wrong with the calculation code or am I not translating the output well enough.

UI:

```
require(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Textmining Tool v0.1"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose PDF',
            accept = c(
              'text/pdf',
              '.pdf' )),
  fileInput('file2', 'Choose TXT,CSV',
            accept = c(
              'text/csv',
              'text/comma-separated-values',
              'text/tab-separated-values',
              'text/plain',
              '.csv',
              '.tsv'
            )

)),
mainPanel(
  textOutput("plot")
)   
  )
)
)
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")  
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")
library(memoise)


 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


 terms <- reactive({

 output$plot <- renderPlot({

in1  <- input$file2 

text <- readLines(in1)
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", 
 x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("dutch"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 10)

wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1, scale = c(2,0.5),
         max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
         colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/word-cloud.html?

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru Yea I have, when I saw it I thought I had all I needed. However, I'm likely not smart enough :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code at the `readLines` function. 
the parameter of  readLines` should be a path to the file. Now it's a dataframe.

[As written here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/fileInput.html), the result of fileInput is a dataframe with multiple columns.

If you modify your code by selecting the datapath row from the dataframe. It should work

```
text <- readLines(in1)
```

should be changed to:

```
text <- readLines(in1$datapath)
```